# Redshift - Divide by Zero Behavior

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I am trying to query my Redshift Cluster using Python and psycopg2.
Please refer the details below :

```
for i in x:
    function_name(p1,p2)

def function_name(parameter_one,parameter_two):
    try:
        //Create Query
       //Create query dynamically


        //Run query here
        SELECT (SELECT SUM(value)
        FROM schemaName.tableName
        WHERE primary_key = 12532
        AND   TO_CHAR(tr_datetime,'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') > '201709162130'
        AND   TO_CHAR(tr_datetime,'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') <= '201709162145')/(SELECT SUM(value)
                                                                        FROM schemaName.tableName
                                                                        WHERE primary_key = = 12542
                                                                        AND   TO_CHAR(tr_datetime,'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') > '201709162130'
                                                                        AND   TO_CHAR(tr_datetime,'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') <= '201709162145');

    except Exception as exception:
        print("Error-----------------------------------")
        error = 'Error on line {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno), type(exception).__name__, exception
        message = str(error)
        print("Error message " + str(exception))
        print("EXCEPTION OCCURRED" + message)
```

The problem I am facing is whenever I encounter `Divide by zero` my program stop executing. I get the following message. Please refer the stack trace below :

```
2018-12-21 13:50:36 -- EXCEPTION OCCURRED in module x for 12532
2018-12-21 13:50:36 -- EXCEPTION OCCURRED in module x for 12532
13:50:36
2018-12-21 13:50:36 -- ('Error on line 1062', 'QueryCanceledError', QueryCanceledError('Divide by zero\n',))
2018-12-21 13:50:36 -- ('Error on line 1062', 'QueryCanceledError', QueryCanceledError('Divide by zero\n',))
13:50:36
2018-12-21 13:50:36 -- EXCEPTION OCCURRED in module x for primary key 12532
2018-12-21 13:50:36 -- EXCEPTION OCCURRED in module x for primary key 12532
13:50:36
2018-12-21 13:50:36 -- ('Error on line 1001', 'InternalError', InternalError('current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block\n',))
2018-12-21 13:50:36 -- ('Error on line 1001', 'InternalError', InternalError('current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block\n',))
13:50:36
2018-12-21 13:50:36 -- EXCEPTION OCCURRED in module x for 12532
2018-12-21 13:50:36 -- EXCEPTION OCCURRED in module x for 12532
13:50:36
2018-12-21 13:50:36 -- ('Error on line 1001', 'InternalError', InternalError('current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block\n',))
2018-12-21 13:50:36 -- ('Error on line 1001', 'InternalError', InternalError('current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block\n',))
```

My question is why my connection is closed ?
Why I am getting `current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`, I was expecting the program to proceed with other iterations, since my code is encapsulated in try/catch block.

It will be great if somebody could help me to understand the root cause and the background behavior of Redshift and Python.

Comment: Check to see if the pyscopg2 connection is being closed or not at any error. Also look into the documentation for commit, that might help as well

Comment: @simplycoding : I checked the connection, the connection was open. But the issue is resolved as soon as I added commit in my exception block. I would like to understand why the commit was needed to continue the execution of my program.